# MinGW custom export function name with stdcall

Tags: c, export, mingw, stdcall

I need to export function

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
int __stdcall MyFunc(int a,int b)
{
    return a*2+b*b;
}
```

Strictly with "MyFunc" export name, not MyFunc@8
MSVC allows do this via .def files, but how to do this in MinGW?

I really need to have stdcall calling convention

Comment: change __stdcall to __cdecl

Comment: As I said, I strictly need __stdcall, so this not an option

Comment: well, __stdcall and 32bit mode are why you have decorated names.  You can't do stdcall in 32 bit without it.  In 64 bit mode, the names are never decorated whichever mode you are in.

Comment: Try adding [-Wl,--kill-at](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.31/ld/Options.html#index-_002d_002dkill_002dat) to the linker command.

Comment: This works! Thank you very much